# How to curve center of container in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I try to make a container like this:

[image: Screenshot]

And I don't want to use another widget on top of that. I need that curved space to be transparent.

I don't know how to create a custom clipper for this example. Can you help me?

Comment: you may have luck with custom svg

Comment: you are looking for notched shaped bottomNavBar

Comment: check how this https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/90c64ed42ba53a52d18f0cb3b17666c8662ed2a0/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/notched_shapes.dart#L39 gets the `Path` - you can copy/paste the code or directly call `getOuterPath` method

Comment: @pskink Where can i use that `getOuterPath ` method?

Comment: In your clipper code, see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipPath-class.html